# How to properly read in text data

Tags: r, text

I am just getting started with text analysis in r. By reading in some example text data I get the following result.

```
sms_raw <- read.csv("sms_spam.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> str(sms_raw)
'data.frame':   5559 obs. of  2 variables:
$ type         : chr  "ham" "ham" "ham" "spam,\"complimentary 4 STAR Ibiza 
Holiday or Â£10,000 cash needs your URGENT collection. 09066364349 NOW from 
Landline not to l"| __truncated__ ...
$ text.........: chr  "Hope you are having a good week. Just checking 
in;;;;;;;;;" "K..give back my thanks.;;;;;;;;;" "Am also doing in cbe only. 
But have to pay.;;;;;;;;;" "" ...
```

It seems to me as if the variables are not getting seperated properly. Further analyzing the data with the head function I get the following result:

```
head(sms_raw)

type
1                                                                                                                                                                    
ham
2                                                                                                                                                                    
ham
3                                                                                                                                                                    
ham
4 spam,"complimentary 4 STAR Ibiza Holiday or Â£10,000 cash needs your 
URGENT collection. 09066364349 NOW from Landline not to lose out! 
Box434SK38WP150PPM18+";;;;;;;;;
5                                                                                                                                                                   
spam
6                                                                                                                                                                    
ham

text.........
1                                                                                                                 
Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in;;;;;;;;;
2                                                                                                                                           
K..give back my thanks.;;;;;;;;;
3                                                                                                                       
Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.;;;;;;;;;
```

Does anybody have suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: it would be helpful to add a few lines of the csv file

Comment: type,text
ham,Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in
ham,Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.
spam,"complimentary 4 STAR Ibiza Holiday or Â£10,000 cash needs your URGENT collection. 09066364349 NOW from Landline not to lose out! Box434SK38WP150PPM18+"
spam,okmail: Dear Dave this is your final notice to collect your 4* Tenerife Holiday or #5000 CASH award! Call 09061743806 from landline. TCs SAE Box326 CW25WX 150ppm
ham,Aiya we discuss later lar... Pick u up at 4 is it?
ham,Are you this much buzy
ham,Please ask mummy to call father

Comment: I do not understand the headers. can you post just the 1st line?

Comment: Did you try `read.csv2`? It has `sep = ';'` as default.

Comment: It seems to me as if some special characters may be the cause for my problem

Comment: 1st line is: type,text

Comment: I did not use read.csv2 because the seperator in my data is a comma

Answer (score 0):

Try `data.table::fread("sms_spam.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep=";")`

## EDIT

you can try:
`input_file<-readLines("/path/of/sms_spam.csv")`

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is the default in `fread`, so it isn't necessary to include it (it won't hurt though ;-) )

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately it did not work. I get a huge warning message. Also when further analyzing the data with the str function I suddenly get 10 variables instead of the two variables that I was trying to analyze

Comment: Add the warning you get and post a link to the csv as well

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In data.table::fread("sms_spam.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";") :
  Bumped column 2 to type character on data row 63, field contains ') love Pete x x x'. Coercing previously read values in this column from logical, integer or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump)....etc

Comment: the csv file seems screwed up. Send a link so I can take a look

Comment: ok the verdict is that the current file does not have the csv format. I edited the answer appropriately. You can now import the data via `readLines`

Comment: Using the head function I get the following:
[1] "type,text;;;;;;;;;" 
[2] "ham,Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in;;;;;;;;;"                                                                                                                  
[3] "ham,K..give back my thanks.;;;;;;;;;"                                                                                                       
[4] "ham,Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.;;;;;;;;;"[5] "\"spam,\"\"complimentary 4 STAR Ibiza Holiday or Â£10,000 cash needs your URGENT collection.

Comment: Any idea how to proceed

Comment: As I mentioned before the file is not in a standard CSV format. Hence either modify the input file OR use readLines